# Unclear what the Redis "Render cache entries with most variations " means in the Redis report

Tags: caching

We've recently started using Redis, and the report page shows a "Render cache entries with most variations" list. I've got about a dozen items that look like this:
`entity_view:block:primaryfootermiddle: 1823 (route, url.site)` - one for each of the standard header and footer elements/blocks of the page. These headers and footers are all the same on all pages of the site.

My *assumption* is that that 1800+ number indicates that there are 1800+ variations of these blocks, but since these are all the same on every page, shouldn't it be *1* variation?

Am I misunderstanding something here or do we have something wrong with how we are caching these blocks?

Comment: It seems likely the “route” context is causing the variations. Does your block need to vary for every single route? If not, you probably want to find what’s adding that context and stop it

Comment: I don't think I want it to vary for every single route. The blocks and the content/links within the blocks are all the same across pages. There are also some blocks in the Redis report that it makes sense to have a lot of variations - things like "Hello $username" or whatever.

Comment: Which kind of block plugin is `primaryfootermiddle`. How do you add content to it?

Comment: I'm actually not quite sure - this is an inherited site and I'm more of a sysadmin than dev... I think it is just a Custom Block.  I can add/edit the content through the Custom Block Library. For the style/positioning of the blocks I have to use a twig template.

Comment: What field types are in the block type? How is the display mode configured? The url.site context looks like you display an absolute link, which is not necessary in most cases. What do you put in the body field, if the block has one, other than static content?

Comment: They are all just a single body field with static HTML content. I have a strong suspicion at this point that the header and footer sections of the site were just built all wrong.